# java.lang.outofmemory exception jvm heap size insufficient

Tags: java

I tried to read a text file which have only one line. File size is over 50Mb. When I tried to read it using the following code it gives

> java.lang.outofmemory exception jvm
>   heap size insufficient

I change the java heap memory to 1GB . But still it gives the same exception.

> set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m

I use foollowing code pragment to read the file.

> BufferedReader Filein1=new
>   BufferedReader(new FileReader( new
>   File( "C:\ABC\MsgStream.txt" )));
>                   s=Filein1.readLine();

Can some one please tell me how to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JAVA_OPTS environment variable is only respected by certain applications (for example the wrapper scripts that are typically used to launch Tomcat).  The `java` command doesn't pay any attention to it.

You need to put the options on the `java` command line ... before the classname; e.g.

```
java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m ... some.pkg.MainClass ...
```

(A 1Gb heap should be more than adequate for buffering a 50Mb file.)

Comment: I am using the netbeans IDE to run the application. So how can I Use your option there. Can I run it with the jar file created after build the project in NB. java -jar -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m abc.jar. Is this correct..

Answer (score 0):

Are JAVA_OPTS actually being run in the output? You may need to actually put them on the command line you're running, or include $JAVA_OPTS on it.

Comment: I run 'set java_opt' in the command promt. It is not included in my code.

Comment: @ganuke how do you run the program? Are you typing, at a command prompt, `java MyMainClass` or something like that? Or are you clicking a button somewhere. If you're using an IDE to run it, it's possible it cached the JAVA_OPTS setting on load, and won't reload them until you restart the IDE (or some other reload mechanism.)

Comment: I' runnig the programme using netBeans. I did restart the IDE after setting the environment variable. But it didnt work

Comment: try running it from the command line, or changing a netbeans setting for how you run programs. (I don't use netbeans so I can't help with that part :-X)

Answer (score 0):

It's **_JAVA_OPTIONS**  not **JAVA_OPTS**

If you have a class like

```
public class Test {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
   System.out.println("value : " + System.getProperty("foo"));
 }
}
```

then you should get

```
> set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dfoo=bar
> java Test
> value : bar
```